# How to control which apps has access to my connection?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, data-connection, sony-xperia-l

I'm looking for how to control which application has access to network. In my country it costs bit higher for data connections. I don't have access to wifi networks always when I'm travelling. Sometimes when I try to check my mail by turning my data on I will have to wait till all the new check ins of swarm come in my phone to get loaded my emails. Or sometimes when I try to check in swarm I have to wait till all the mails loaded kind of. How can I limit which application only to use when I try to open my data connection. Assume I want to check my email, so when I try to open my data connection for that I should be able to turn off all the other applications using network except mail application. 
I'm using unrooted sony xperia L with jelly bean OS and I cannot root my phone.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings, data usage. Press the apps you want not to use data, and scroll down and select "Disable background data". Now the app won't connect to the Internet if connected on mobile network or mobile hotspot. Please note that if you open the app, it will be allowed to use your data connection, this is only for background data.